# jQuery remember the div content even the page refresh

Tags: jquery, refresh

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addButton').click(function() {
        var newHTML = "";
        newHTML += '<p><label> Answer Type</label><select name="ans_type[]"><option value="Image">Image</option><option value="Text">Text</option></select></p><p class="text"><label> Enter Answer</label><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="ans_text[]"></textarea></p><p  class="image"><label> Upload Image</label> <br/><input type="file" name="ans_image[]" class="btn"/></p>';
        $('#sandbox').append(newHTML);
    });
    $(document).on("change", "select[name*='ans_type']", function() {
        var answer = $(this).val();
        if (answer == "Image") {
            $(".text").hide();
            $(".image").show();
        } else {
            $(".text").show();
            $(".image").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<div id="sandbox">
<p>
    <label> Answer Type</label>
    <select name="ans_type[]">
        <option value="Image">Image</option>
        <option value="Text">Text</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p class="text">
    <label> Enter Answer</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="ans_text[]"></textarea>
</p>
<p class="image">
    <label> Upload Image</label> <br/>
    <input type="file" name="ans_image[]" class="btn"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label> Is Correct Answer</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="isCorrectAnswer[]"/>
</p>
```

After I click the Add button, the textbox and drop down list and upload image field will duplicate one. But when I click submit button the added textbox and drop down list image upload gone, how could I modify so it will remain even after the page refresh?

Comment: put the content in a cookie using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use special jQuery plugin for cookies: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

There is an answered question here about cookies and jQuery:
[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: Let said when the user submit form, and validation fail bounce back but how to ratain the field with the input value